# problem with ubuntu 21.10 and nodejs

Tags: upgrade, nodejs, do-release-upgrade, release-management, 21.10

I just upgrade my Ubuntu from 21.04 to 21.10.
I did the upgrade by the `do-release-upgrade` command so, the upgrade is finished and my problems begin: I use GO and nodejs packages, after upgrading the system can't use nodejs or even reinstall it.

When I run the `node -V` command the output is like this: `node: bad option: -V`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node: bad option: -V` try `node -v`

Answer (score 0):

I got this:
I'm trying to use the `nvm` package on my system
with this package, I can use multi versions of nodes on my system and switch between them easily.